# MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata returns weird output for non-English words/characters

Tags: android

I'm trying to get metadata (like title, album, author of the song) from audio files (.mp3):

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mMetaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mMetaRetriever.setDataSource(path);
String pathMeta =  mMetaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

But if metadata isn't in English, but in some other language (Russian, Japanese and others) it returns weird output (characters).

Issue happens on newest API 20-25
and it works ok with 19 (KitKat 4.4.4) and I guess it works ok for previous version of Android

If someone met such issue and tested .mp3 files with non-English metadata 
how did you solve this issue?